# Apache Superset Login Screen

Tags: apache-superset

I want to change login screen background image but did not find related files on superset-frontend folder. I'm using apache superset docker compose latest version. Where can I find login page file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on how to change UI images.
https://medium.com/@supreethmc/superset-customization-of-the-logo-within-a-docker-container-eccff32a6e39

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw this article but what I'm trying to do is changing background image of login screen. This article explains how to change logo only.